# How to clone an array when containing null element in java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, clone

If I want to clone an array of objects, but there are some null elements in the array, how to implement clone() method? For example:

```
class A {};

class B implements Cloneable {
    A[] arrayFoo = new A[maxNumber];
    // let some elements in arrayFoo be null
    // now I want to implement a clone method
    public B clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B result = (B) super.clone()
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will throw a null pointer exception. How to fix this bug?

Comment: Your code is can't compiled...`class` not `Class`, `implements` not `implement`

Comment: And even after I fixed it, it doesn't throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: What's version of java you are using?@Iswanto

Comment: @user1237575: I'm using java 6

Answer (score 2):

Cloning an array performs a shallow copy, and null values are copied properly. It doesn't produce any NullPointerException, unless the array variable itself is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (It will not throw NullPointerException):

```
class A {};


class B implements Cloneable {
    public static final int MAX_NUMBER = 42;
    A[] arrayFoo = new A[MAX_NUMBER];
    // let some elements in arrayFoo be null
    // now I want to implement a clone method
    public B clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B result = (B) super.clone();
        return result;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = b1.clone();

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**
When you post questions like this, **ALWAYS** specify exactly at which line of code the NullPointerException occurs, and **ALWAYS** make sure that that specific line is posted in the question.

---

My guess (if you're from a C++ background) is that you are calling clone on a member variable only declared as:

```
B b;
```

That would throw a NullPointerException, but not because of the `clone` implementation. `B b;`does not instantiate anything in Java. It merely declares a reference which can point to a `B` object. But the reference is initialized as `null`. Hence, calling clone on `b` would be trying to call clone on a non-existing object.

Comment: Your last code example doesn't compile in Java. Data members and arrays do have default initializations, but local variables don't.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Sorry. You're right. You'd think that all the times I have had to initialize Input/OutputStreams to null outside try/catch blocks would make it impossible to overlook that fact. But unfortunately, it didn't. I updated the answer to reflect a similar, but compilable scenario.